# Python Pandas: itemsize functions throws AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'itemsize'

Tags: pandas

I am new to Python Pandas, and, as part of that, I wanted to create a pandas.Series and print the itemsize of the Series. However, while I was doing that, it returned an attribute error.

Following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
s = pd.Series(data)
print(s.itemsize)
```

This however **does not return** the *itemsize* and throws the following error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USER\filename.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(s.itemsize)
          ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5902, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'itemsize'```

What might the reason for this be?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably confused it with [`numpy.ndarray.itemsize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.itemsize.html) in [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy).

In *pandas*, it's [`pandas.Series.dtype.itemsize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dtype.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
s = pd.Series(data)
```

Output :

```
print(s.dtype.itemsize)
#8
```